# making a Table in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I'm trying to make a table in Matlab and initialze it with zeros so I did it in this way:

```
z =zeros(4,4);
exTab = table(z,'RowNames',{'row1' 'row2' 'row3' 'row4' }, 'VariableNames',{'column','column2','column3','column4'})
```

and I received this error

> The VariableNames property must contain one name for each variable in the table

it recognizes all columns of the zeros as just one column, how to do it in the right way?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html#bveh4ux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array2table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html) instead of [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html). i.e.

```
z = zeros(4,4);
exTab = array2table(z,'RowNames',{'row1','row2','row3','row4'},...
    'VariableNames',{'column1','column2','column3','column4'});
```

This, as expected, gives:

```
>> exTab
exTab =
  4×4 table
            column1    column2    column3    column4
            _______    _______    _______    _______
    row1       0          0          0          0   
    row2       0          0          0          0   
    row3       0          0          0          0   
    row4       0          0          0          0
```